# How to secure access uploaded file on wordpress/PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, security, file-upload

I have to create a form on a wordpress site where people can upload files. I want to secure the upload folder because files are private. There is no authentification. What is the more secure way to do that. i have to be sure that no one will be able to access files execpt me

Comment: Have you try something? have you made some search for online tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow some steps like:

1. Use random number with time stamp to save the file name.
2. To prevent the folder from unauthorized access, disable directory listing using htaccess
3. You can also deny all in htaccess so no one can access the folder
4. Use plugin like Protect uploads to make more secure your upload folder, but they do the same things mentioned above.

Comment: thanks, i think i will use as well folder encryption with certificates